# What signifies the @Input decorator on the component property in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

In The component I found the `@Input` decorator attached to the property

```
@Input() description: string;
```

the property description is used in the html as the interpolation

```
<div>{{description}}</div>
```

The question is what signifies the `@Input`? when and why it is used?

Comment: Example application http://www.freakyjolly.com/example-app-share-data-between-angular-components-using-input-decorator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Input` means that a consuming component can set/bind the property like so:

```
<my-comp [description]="someProperty"></my-comp>
```

It does *not* affect the ability for the component itself to use the property. Similarly `@Output` signifies an event that can be subscribed to.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Input` decorator signifies that the component property is available for view binding.
The power of the angular binding infrastructure allows us to use any component property as a bindable property by attaching the `@Input` decorator to it.